# Hacer FOCUS a div mediante JQuery

Tags: jquery

Después de realizar la validación de un conjunto de radiobutton necesito que el foco del formulario se desplace hasta un elemento del formulario.

He creado una función que funciona perfectamente (valida los campos y activa div con mensaje de error) pero no desplaza el foco hasta el elemento indicado.

¿Alguién me puede indicar que estoy haciendo mal?

Código html:

```
<div id="txtotronodo" style="display: none;">
<input type="text" id="reply6" name="txtotronodo" class="form-control col-sm-12" placeholder="Indique el nodo">
</div>
```

Código JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function validaNodo() {
        var nodo = $("input[name=nodo]:radio:checked").length;
        if (nodo !== 1) {
            $("#nodo").css("display", "block");
            $(document).on('focus', 'reply6');
            $('reply6').focus();
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            $("#nodo").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
});
```

Un saludo y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Creo que te estás liando. Para mover el foco a un `<input>` lo único que necesitas es la línea `$('reply6').focus();`. pero te faltaba indicar que "reply6" es un **ID** con el uso de "#", por lo que tendría que quedarte: `$('#reply6').focus();` Esta línea te sobraría por completo: `$(document).on('focus', 'reply6');`

Comment: Cierto MyGuel, muchas gracias por la aclaración. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El foco solamente se le puede hacer a elementos que puedan tenerlo. Un `<div>` no es uno de ellos, `<input>`, `<select>`, `<a>`... si lo són.

**Ejemplo:**

```js
$(function () {
  $(document).on('focus', 'div', foco_div);
  $(document).on('focus', 'input', foco_input);
  
  $('div').focus();
  $('input').focus();
});

function foco_input () {
  console.log('Input: ¡Me focuseaste, maldito seas!');
}

function foco_div () {
  console.log('Div: ¡No me puedes tocar, MUAHAHAHA!');
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <p>No me puedes hacer foco, que le vamos a hacer.</p>
</div>

<input type="text" value="Hazme todo el foco que quieras">
```

**Referencia:** [focus()](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la aclaración. Entonces en el caso de que quiere hacer el focus sobre un input en concreto, ¿como debería hacerlo?.

Un saludo.

Comment: Si te sirvió la respuesta haz el favor de marcarla como aceptada para que se considere cerrada ^^

Comment: En mi ejemplo se ve: `$('#id_de_mi_input').focus();`

Comment: Hola MyGuel.
Disculpa pero al hacer lo que me comentas me indica un error.

Este es mi código html:

<div id="txtotronodo" style="display: none;">
                        <input type="text" id="reply6" name="txtotronodo" class="form-control col-sm-12" placeholder="Indique el nodo">
                    </div>

Y este el código jquery:
$(document).on('focus', 'reply6');
$('reply6').focus();

Sin embargo en el error me indica es: TypeError: can't assign to property "guid" on "reply6": not an object

Comment: Mejor actualiza tu pregunta con el código de lo que llevas intentado, así será más sencillo verlo ^^